# SQL server linked server to PostgreSQL query conversion of TOP clause is not converted

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, performance, linked-server

I created a SQL linked server to connect to PostgreSQL 11, and issue a query like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [LinkedServer_PostgreSQL].[DBname].[dbo].[TableName] a;
```

It is very slow and seems to take forever, I ended up killing the query every time. Upon investigation, I found the query on the PostgreSQL server is selecting all rows, the `TOP N` row clause on the PostgreSQL is not converted. That's why the query cannot finish, because the table has more than 10 million rows.

As I cannot replace TOP clause using LIMIT clause on SQL server. This really beats me. Help, anyone?

Comment: Returning 10 million rows shouldn't take forever though. Depending on the hardware I would expect that to run in "seconds" maybe if the network is slow in a couple of minutes - depending on the data in the table obviously. If every table contains 100MB text data, then of course this will be slow

Comment: Have you tried creating a view on the PostgreSQL server that selects with limit 1 and then calling that view from SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks guys, I believe it took "forever" is because it rounds on a busy storage system and I was wrong about the 10 million rows, it was actually 70 millions rows ( ouch..) . And I like the idea of creating a view on PostgreSQL, sounds like a innovative work-around. Thanks a lot, I will test it.